# Having trouble with React useState method

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm trying to make a site with moviedb api, but I had a problem with my setState method. My setMovies dont apply the values to state. and when I log the movie state, the array is empty
Can you help me?

my code:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState<IMovies[]>([]);
const [searchMovie, setSearchMovie] = useState('a'); // Define o valor inicial como A para gerar as primeiras lista de filmes.


async function loadMovies() {
    await api.get(`?query=${searchMovie}&api_key=${key}`)
          .then(response => {
                const data = response.data.results;
                setMovies(data);
                console.log(movies)
     });
 }

 useEffect(() => {
    loadMovies();
 }, [searchMovie]);
```

Comment: You should double check that `movies` is not actually being set by moving the `console.log(movies)` outside of the `loadMovies` function. Note that you are never actually changing the value of `movies`; `setState` schedules that state to be changed, but it doesn't affect the `movies` value on this particular render

Comment: This isn't the issue, but you are also mixing patterns here with using both 'await' and 'then'. If you want to use 'then', don't bother with async/await here. If you want to use `await`, drop the then, and use `const response = api.get(...)`

Comment: Ok, I will try thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
const [searchMovie, setSearchMovie] = useState('a');

useEffect(async() => {
     await api.get(`?query=${searchMovie}&api_key=${key}`).then(response => {       
        setMovies([...response.data.results]);
    });
     console.log(movies)
}, [searchMovie]);
```